# Is there a .Net 6 equivalent for WebApp.Start<Startup>(url: baseAddress)?

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022

I am trying to replace this line for .Net 6.  It seems to be using Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.  Is there a equivalent from the 4.8 to .Net 6 for this conversion?

```
_logger.Standard($"Starting Web Service on {baseAddress}");
_server = WebApp.Start<Startup>(url: baseAddress);
_logger.Standard("Web service is started.");
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here. Are you just wanting to choose the base address for an ASP.NET Core app?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[Looks like](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/owin?view=aspnetcore-6.0) you can [get `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Owin` from Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Owin/) and use that instead for .NET Core 6.